# Fitness Tracking App | Ruby on Rails | ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I’m building a fitness training tracking app and I need some help getting my head around the model configuration and associations needed.

To make things simple I’m breaking this app down into training sessions, activities and workout sets.

The user will log in and create a new training session that will record the results from each workout set. The training session will record the activity/ies that were used in that session (e.g. press ups - 4 sets to exhaustion), and the results (e.g. how many press ups were achieved on each workout set).

The activity will be preloaded (press ups 4 sets, sit ups 6 sets, etc) and be available to the user to view and add to a training session.

The user will then record the result from each workout set (e.g. Set 1 = 20, set 2 = 15...). The number of workout sets will be defined by the preloaded activity.

In summary, the result will be recorded at the workout set level and the be associated with an activity and a training session.

```
class TrainingSession
    has_many :activities
    has_many :workout_sets, :through => :activities 
end

class Activity
    belongs_to :training_session
    has_many :workout_sets 
end

class WorkoutSets
    belongs_to :activity
end
```

Is this the best way to structure this? Is there any shortfalls I need to be aware of?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Is this the best way to structure this or is there a better way?

Comment: Seems that you're missing a model for `Workout`, but otherwise looks like a workable solution.